# watir webdriver browser will not goto url

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, browser, watir-webdriver

When I run the .rb file, the browser opens, but doesn't go to the desired url. Screen stays blank white. When I hit control c in the terminal to quit, I get:

`/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.49.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:90:in 'connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (xxx.x.x.x:xxxx) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)`

I used simple code to test and still no luck:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox #:profile => profile
browser.goto('http://google.com')
```

Comment: did you tried downgrading to fireFox 45 as mention by by Casper?

Comment: @AnurajR That's exactly what I did and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an open issue on this for Selenium:     https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/835

Most often proposed solution:
**Downgrade to Firefox 45**.